# Dropdown validation, focus method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want someone to select an option, but not the first option `-- Select --.`

**HTML**

```
<select name = "sources" id = "brandname" required onblur = "selectText()" />
     <option value = "select"> -- Select -- </option>
     <option value = "referal"> Referal </option>
     <option value = "justdial"> Justdial </option>
     <option value = "sulekha"> Sulekha </option>
     <option value = "website"> Website </option>
     <option value = "others"> Others </option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
if (document.getElementById("brandname").value == "select") {
    alert("Please select the required value");
    document.getElementById("brandname")[1].focus();
}
```

It executes the alert message, after that it moved to the next field. But it supposed to be sticked with that dropdown until and unless the select value changed to any other value.

What is wrong with the code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, try adding a `return false;` after the `.focus()` line

Comment: i did, then also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>v1</option>
    <option>v2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var s = document.getElementById("mySelect");
```

**Check the selected value with**

```
s.options[s.selectedIndex].value // Keep this in mind
```

If statement:

```
if(s.options[s.selectedIndex].value == "select") {
    alert("A value is required!");
    s.focus(); 
}
```

(Your focus without `[1]`:

```
document.getElementById("brandname").focus();
```

)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/19cow7b0/5)

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please **accept** the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `[1]` from the focus statement.As `getElementById` **always** returns **single** object.

```js
var selectText =function(){
if(document.getElementById("brandname").value == "select") {
            alert("Please select the required value");
            document.getElementById("brandname").focus();
        }}
```

```html
<select name = "sources" id = "brandname" required onblur = "selectText()" />
     <option value = "select"> -- Select -- </option>
     <option value = "referal"> Referal </option>
     <option value = "justdial"> Justdial </option>
     <option value = "sulekha"> Sulekha </option>
     <option value = "website"> Website </option>
     <option value = "others"> Others </option>
</select>
```